# Creating a (.NET 6 based) website project with ASP.NET Core and React (TypeScript) in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have been trying to set up an ASP.NET Core + React (TypeScript) web app project in Visual Studio 2022, but couldn't succeed in doing so. There are no proper stacks/suites(?) in the Visual Studio 2022 create project dialog (`File > New > Project...`) that suit my needs.

I then tried what [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022) say - and it works - but when I do the same for React TypeScript (i.e., using `Standalone TypeScript React Template` instead of `Standalone JavaScript React Template`) it doesn't work because this template doesn't have an `Add integration for Empty ASP.NET Web API project.` option in its setup (but the JavaScript template does).

How do I create an ASP.NET Core + React (TypeScript) project then?

I did see some modified and new files when the ASP.NET Core Web API integration option was enabled during the React.js (not TypeScript) setup. Can I copy those ASP.NET Core Web API integration files and their content, re-write the JavaScript files in TypeScript, and add those files (`*.ts` instead of `*.js`, etc.) in the TypeScript template? Or is there any other (official) method to properly set up an ASP.NET Core + React (TypeScript) project in Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 3):

This  is the [guide](https://www.nolanbradshaw.ca/net-react-typescript-template) do you need, just a consideration I changed this piece of code in **aspnetcore-react.ts**

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    '.env.development.local',
    `BROWSER=none
    HTTPS=true
    SSL_CRT_FILE=${certFilePath}
    SSL_KEY_FILE=${keyFilePath}`,
);
```

**BROWSER=none** Start without opening url in the browser because should be opened by .NET proxy

**HTTPS=true** Dev server to serve pages over HTTPS. Uses the .NET  self-signed certificate

Comment: followed the steps but 2 tabs are opened,one is React app and one shows:   Launching the SPA proxy... 'This page will automatically redirect to https://localhost:44483 when the SPA proxy is ready.'     and keeps loading... then a cmd window shows:  "Something is already running on port 3000.Would you like to run the app on another port instead? » (Y/n)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "dotnet new react" command to create a template React and C# project. Here is a guide to upgrade that template code to TypeScript and Vite (also includes Azure AD, but I don't think you need that).

https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/

Yesterday, the Visual Studio team released two much welcome improvements in 17.8 Preview 1.

1. [The React and ASP.NET Core Visual Studio template supports TypeScript.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-8-preview-1-has-arrived/#new-react-typescript-and-asp-net-combined-templates)
2. [The React and ASP.NET Core Visual Studio template supports Vite.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-7-now-available/#supporting-vite-for-react-and-vue-new-project-creation)

I was not able to get the new template to deploy (even using the self-contained deployment option) so I am not recommending it just yet.